# Emailing submitted form of a SQL array

Tags: php, sql, odbc, html-email

~edit
I have been working this same issue for a few days now. I am trying to change individual fields (dimensions) within an array pulled from a query, then email myself the result. Here is what I have so far...

```
//form.php
    echo "<table id='tableTop'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Pick Ticket</th>";
    echo "<th>Item ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Bin</th>";
    echo "<th>Length</th>";
    echo "<th>Width</th>";
    echo "<th>Height</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($key = odbc_fetch_array($rows)){
echo "<form id='Email_Fix' method='post' action='mail.php'>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='PT_N' value=".  $key['PT_N'] ." readonly></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='Item_ID' value=".  $key['Item_ID'] ." readonly></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='Bin' value=".  $key['Bin'] ." readonly></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='tel' step='0.01' pattern='[0-9\.]*' name='Length' value=" . $key['Length'] . " size='10'></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='tel' step='0.01' pattern='[0-9\.]*' name='Width' value=" . $key['Width'] . " size='10'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='tel' step='0.01' pattern='[0-9\.]*' name='Height' value=" . $key['Height'] . " size='10'></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
```

The part of code "name='". $key['PT_N'] ."_length' is a feeble attempt at trying to change the names of the input fields dynamically. The issue I am having, I need to be able to call these fields on a mail.php page, but I haven't figured out how to reference each one by $_POST...

```
//mail.php

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
}
```

The above code helped quite a bit, yet it is only returning one line from form.php. Here is the output I get... however; there are actually 20 rows to this... "No trade secrets have been published" :P

> POST parameter 'PT_N' has '4338892'POST parameter 'Item_ID' has
>   'KOHK-14484-BGD'POST parameter 'Bin' has 'BOXFIX01'POST parameter
>   'Length' has '3.000000000'POST parameter 'Width' has '2.500000000'POST
>   parameter 'Height' has '2.000000000'

~update

I got it to work, yet... I'm taking it one step further and created a function

```
$msg = "<p> Mike!</p><p> Here is your stuff!\n\n
<table id='tableTop'>
<tr>
<th>Pick Ticket</th>
<th>Item ID</th>
<th>Bin</th>
<th>Length</th>
<th>Width</th>
<th>Height</th>

</tr>";
function Fixit($loop, $num){

foreach($_POST[$loop] as $key => $num){
   echo "<td>" . $num . "</td>";
};
};

$msg1 = " <tr>" . Fixit('PT_N', '0') && Fixit('Item_ID', '1') && Fixit('Bin', '2') && Fixit('Length', '3') && Fixit('Width', '4') && Fixit('Height', '5') ."</tr>";

echo $msg, $msg1;
```

That doesn't work?

Comment: The string on line 8 isn't closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   // $key = name of the input
   // $value = value of the input
}
```

Comment: Could you help me by explaining that a little more?
So, the way I am getting it is that $key is still the array and it is pushing the  value of $key to the variable $value?

Comment: When you click that submit button, all of the inputs will be posted to mail.php. In mail.php you can use the foreach above to access each of the inputs.

Comment: Thank you! I did a dump because it was erroring out, but it only pulls one row out of 2+ (sometimes 20)... Should I do a While ($value = foreach($_POST as $key => $value))

Comment: Each input must have a unique name (unless they are radio buttons or checkboxes). If you have 10 text inputs with the name `PT_N`, only the last one is submitted because each one overwrites the previous.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!

I had to set each input name as: